# How to reverse a filter class in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django

I needed to filter models instances with custom function, and using

```
Post.objects.filter(func)
```

didnt help, I got a type error cause "object is not iterable, so I went with

```
    def filter_posts(x):
        if x.author in followed_author_list:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

```
posts = filter(filter_posts, Post.objects.all())
return render(request, 'main.html', {'posts':posts })
```

And it worked, but now I cant reverse the list, cause I want to order it so newest will be last. If I use list() on it, then posts stop appearing on my website at all, cause I assume its not a different type?..

Question is, how do I reverse filter class, or pull this off in general, so I get my posts filtered in reverse order?

Comment: Why do you need a function for this filter? `Post.objects.filter(author__in=followed_author_list)`…?! It's ludicrous to read *`all`* objects into memory and then filter them in Python. You'll need to supply the filter condition in a way that's queryable by a database, and no, that means you can't use functions.

Comment: For custom filters you should take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: @Alombaros thanks! I will definitely look into this :) just learning, so did everything for a small scale website, but I try to learn as much as I can from this project for myself, so this is highly helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
def users_by_active(active: bool):
    users = User.objects.all()
    ids = [user.id for user in users if user.is_active == active]
    return users.filter(id__in=ids)
```

you can make something similar to this function

best of luck

Comment: Please don't read ***the entire database of users*** into memory…!

Comment: thanks for your replay.. yes it is not a memory efficient solution if we have a a lot of users

Comment: @deceze im making it locally just for the sake of learning, so it wont ruin my PC. but i wil definitely look into your tips, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I listened to your comments and started looking how to make query to the DB without loading all of it, to come up to conclusion objects.filter() I mentioned is the lazy method for queries, so my solution is

```
        followed_obj = Following.objects.filter(following_user=current_profile)
    followed_author_list = []
    for followed in followed_obj:
        followed_author_list.append(followed.profile.owner)
    posts = Post.objects.none()
    for author in followed_author_list:
        posts |= Post.objects.filter(author=author)
    posts = posts.order_by('date').reverse()
```

Thanks everyone for your input and helping me become a better developer :)